# Displaying a long string in a spinner without cutting

Tags: android, spinner

In my current app, if the string is too long and doesn't fit into screen it gets cut. How to display rolling text for long strings in a spinner(i have seen that in some apps)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `Spinner` extends `AdapterView` (like `ListView` does) which is backed by an `Adapter` class.

So much like you can customise each row in a `ListView`, you should be able to do the same for your `Spinner` by overriding a method like [`Adapter.getView()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getView%28int,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup%29).

There you could return a simple `TextView` with the `ellipsize` property.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a textview look at the [ellipsize property](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:ellipsize) with the marquee option.

Comment: Sorry but i am using spinner, not textview.